# creating a installer for .net app

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer, installshield

I had created a component in .net. It has more than one msi's , so am planning to go for a master installer. How to create a master installer, how to start with that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a bootstrapper to install multiple MSIs, try [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) for a free solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Setup Project template provided by Visual Studio. This project template lets you create setup projects very fast. There you have to add your different MSIs as dependencies to have them installed.

Alternatively have a look at the different setup and deployment project templates located under "Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment" in the "Add new project" dialog.